# Exporting Hash Table Using Property Dictionary to CSV

Tags: regex, excel, powershell

I can't seem to figure out how to simply export formatted information to a CSV unless I iterate through each item in the object and write to the CSV line by line, which takes forever. I can export values instantly to the CSV, it's just when using the properties dictionary I run into issues.

The TestCSV file is formatted with a column that has IP addresses.

Here's what I have:

```
$CSV = "C:\TEMP\OutputFile.csv"
$RX = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.|dot|\[dot\]|\[\.\])){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
$TestCSV = "C:\TEMP\FileWithIPs.csv"

$spreadsheetDataobject = import-csv $TestCSV
$Finding = $spreadsheetDataObject | Select-String $RX
$Props = @{ #create a properties dictionary
                LineNumber = $finding.LineNumber
                Matches = $finding.Matches.Value
       }
$OBJ = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Props
$OBJ | Select-Object Matches,LineNumber | Export-Csv -Path $CSV -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Please post a few lines of FileWithIPs.csv with the header line.

Comment: ****IP CSV File Headers:

URL,DOMAIN,IP,COUNTRY,STATE,CITY,ISP

****IP CSV File Data:                   
 
hxxp://www.google.com/somepage.htm,google.com,8.8.8.8,US,ND,Black falls,Charter

Comment: So each line of the file has an IP? In this case there's no reason to use the line number?

Comment: There are other files that do not have IP's on all lines. Also, if we want to know where to find a specific IP, the line number is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to work as written. You are using `Import-CSV` which creates an array of objects with properties. The `Select-String` command expects strings as input, not objects. If you want to use `Select-String` you would want to simply specify the file name, or use `Get-Content` on the file, and pass that to `Select-String`. If what you want is the line number, and the IP I think this would probably work just as well if not better for you:

```
$CSV = "C:\TEMP\OutputFile.csv"
$RX = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.|dot|\[dot\]|\[\.\])){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
$TestCSV = "C:\TEMP\FileWithIPs.csv"

$spreadsheetDataobject = import-csv $TestCSV
$spreadsheetDataobject | 
    Where{$_.IP -match $RX} | 
    Select-Object @{l='Matches';e={$_.IP}},@{l='LineNumber';e={[array]::IndexOf($spreadsheetDataobject,$_)+1}} | 
    Export-Csv -Path $CSV -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

**Edit:** wOxxOm is quite right, this answer has considerably more overhead than parsing the text directly like he does. Though, for somebody who's new to PowerShell it's probably easier to understand.

In regards to `$_.IP`, since you use `Import-CSV` you create an array of objects. Each object has properties associated with it based on the header of the CSV file. `IP` was listed in the header as one of your columns, so each object has a property of `IP`, and the value of that property is whatever was in the IP column for that record.

Let me explain the `Select` line for you, and then you'll see that it's easy to add your source path as another column.

What I'm doing is defining properties with a hashtable. For my examples I will refer to the first one shown above. Since it is a hashtable it starts with `@{` and ends with `}`. Inside there are two key/value pairs:

```
l='Matches'
e={$_.IP}
```

Essentially 'l' is short for Label, and 'e' is short for Expression. The label determines the name of the property being defined (which equates to the column header when you export). The expression defines the value assigned to the property. In this case I am really just renaming the IP column to Matches, since the value that I assign for each row is whatever is in the IP field. If you open the CSV in Excel, copy the entire IP column, paste it in at the end, and change the header to Matches, that is basically all I'm doing. So to add the file path as a column we can add one more hashtable to the `Select` line with this:

```
@{
    l='FilePath'
    e={$CSV}
}
```

That adds a third property, where the name is FilePath, and the value is whatever is stored in `$CSV`. That updated `Select` line would look like this:

```
    Select-Object @{l='Matches';e={$_.IP}},@{l='LineNumber';e={[array]::IndexOf($spreadsheetDataobject,$_)+1}},@{l='FilePath'e={$CSV}} |
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it does indeed work. However, I'm honestly having a hard time understanding what you did. The where $_.IP (This is the current object, but what is IP? Then the select object line is mostly foreign to me. The only other thing I'm trying to do is have another column where the current path and file (all together) being searched (which I stored in an array is listed on each line as well.)

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do with my path and filename that's currently being searched:  `$PathArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList`    `$PathArray.add($csvFile)` `$PathArray | ForEach-Object {INSERT CODE YOU HAVE ABOVE}`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much again for this. This really helps me understand what you are doing here. One last question, I'll be searching many CSV files that have different column headers, will this affect my results if the column header isn't IP?

Comment: Yes, it most definitely will. If you do not know your headers then you can't really process the files as CSVs, and instead need to process them as just text. Use wOxxOm's answer in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Any code based on the built-in CSV cmdlets is extremely slow because objects are created for each field on each line, and it's noticeable on large files (for example, code from the other answer takes 900 seconds to process a 9MB file with 100k lines).

If your input CSV file is simple, you can process it as text in less than a second for a 100k lines file:

```
$CSV = .......
$RX = .......
$TestCSV = .......

$line = 0 # header line doesn't count
$lastMatchPos = 0
$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($TestCSV) -replace '"http.+?",', ','
$out = New-Object Text.StringBuilder
ForEach ($m in ([regex]"(?<=,""?)$RX(?=""?,)").Matches($text)) {
    $line += $m.index - $lastMatchPos - 
             $text.substring($lastMatchPos, $m.index-$lastMatchPos).Replace("`n",'').length
    $lastMatchPos = $m.Index + $m.length
    $out.AppendLine('' + $line + ',' + $m.value) >$null
}
if (!(Test-Path $CSV)) {
    'LineNumber,IP' | Out-File $CSV -Encoding ascii
}
$out.ToString() | Out-File $CSV -Encoding ascii -Append
```

The code zaps quoted URLs fields just in the unlikely but possible case those contain a matching IP.

Comment: Hey wOxxOm, I'm attempting to test your code and received an error. "Method invocation failed because [System.Text.StringBuilder] does not contain a method named 'new'" for the $out line. Also, if you have time to comment your code here, it would go a long way to helping me understand exactly what you're doing on each line.

Comment: When I run get-host is shows me at 4, should I upgrade to 5? Also, when I ran the updated version it produces another error "Out-File : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'NoNewline'." I removed that option and the resulting CSV only had the headers "LineNumber" and "IP"

Comment: I should add that my main goal is to have a script that I can point at directories with a regular expression and produce a report that shows where the regular expression matched and what it matched. e.g. The actual matches, the line (if possible, not necessary), the file and directory (full path) of where each match was found.

Comment: PS4 should be fine. Can't say why you've seen the first error though. `NoNewline` is from PS5, so I've removed it. Anyway, I can't really guess what happens on your PC so use PowerShell ISE debugger to see what happens, if you're interested in getting this code running.